# BCS Question (changing data source of a web service)

Tags: web-services, bcs, external-content-type, database, external-data-column

We are going to be building a Web Service (on-premise) to connect our data to SharePoint online (o365) using BCS and OData.

If we migrate our database from one location (in Oracle) to another (e.g. in SQL), and then re-write the web service (on-premise) to connect to the new location, will this impact the existing data rendered in SharePoint?

This would be the exact same data, just migrated to a new environment.  I wouldn't guess it would change anything on the SharePoint side cause its just going out to that same external content type / web service location and doesn't care what the back-end looks like.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that BCS is connected to the web service and not to the DB directly, you should not need to worry about any changes at all.